# If a group $G$ has order $p^n$ where $p$ is a prime, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> If a group $G$ has order $p^n$ where $p$ is a prime, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $p$.

Assume that $G$ is a finite group. Without using the Sylow's theorem, how do I prove this statement? I know induction may work, but what should be the inductive hypothesis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would pick a non-identity element $x$.  Lagrange says the order of $x$ must divide $p^n$, so $|x|=p^k$ for some $1 \leq k \leq n$.  If the order is already $p$, $\langle x \rangle$ has size $p$.  If not, then look at the element $x^{p^{k-1}}$.  It has order $p$, so $\langle x^{p^{k-1}}\rangle$ will be a cyclic subgroup of size $p$.

Comment: That was a very smart move and answers my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** One can avoid induction altogether. Lagrange's Theorem implies that the order of any group element divides the order of the group. What are the factors of $p^n$?

Comment: I am not sure this quite does it.  Of course this cannot happen since the theorem is clearly true by Cauchy's Theorem which gives you an element $x$ of order $p$.  Then $\langle x \rangle$ has order $p$.  All LaGrange says is that every subgroup has order dividing $p^n$.  It is conceivable that all the subgroups have size $p^2$ or something.

Comment: Well, I could see that all the elements of $G$ has order $p^k$ for some $k$ less than $n$. But how does this observation determines the existence of a subgroup with order $p$? Are we looking for an element of order $p$ so it generates such a subgroup? If so how do we know such element exists? Thanks! @Travis

Comment: @CPM I'm not sure quite what your objection is, especially in light of your own solution, which carries out precisely what "order of any group element divides the order of the group" hints at.

Comment: @LewisLi That's not necessarily true: Some elements of $\Bbb Z_{p^n}$ have order $p^n$. Yes, we're looking for an element of order $p$ so that it generates the subgroup: Any nonidentity element $g$ must have order a multiple of $p$; can we then find a power $g^m$ of $g$ such that $g^m$ has order $p$?

Comment: My complaint is that Lagrange only says the size of the subgroups divide the order of the group.  It says nothing about the converse.  Just because $p$ is a factor of $p^n$, there is no reason to believe there to be a subgroup of that size.  Now for cyclic groups, the converse is actually true as my answer highlights.  For cyclic groups of size $n$ every subgroup is cyclic AND for every divisor $k$ of $n$, there is a subgroup of order $k$.

Comment: It's true that Lagrange's Theorem only says that the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group, but the answer specifically states the relevant corollary of Lagrange's Theorem (rather than the theorem itself): "Lagrange's Theorem implies that the order of any group element..." From this corollary (and the hint, "What are the factors of $p^n$?") we have immediately that the order of any element is one of $1, p, p^2, \ldots, p^n$.

Comment: I know this, but it is conceivable then that every non-identity element has order $p^2$ or bigger.  You need more to actually build one that has order $p$ and I felt that was the part the OP was wondering about.  It seems like it was indeed the part they were foggy about.  I just know a lot of students make this converse error with Lagrange, so I wanted to be sure the OP didn't do the same.  Either way, I think the OP has it figured out.  I think you just left the crux of the argument to the OP to fill in.